# Can DateTimeField fields we optimized?

Tags: postgresql, django-models

I have been looking to optimize my database model for Postgres and Django.  The Debug Toolbar highlights that the DateTimeField fields look to be the slowest

For example

```
record_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text='The date the record was updated', db_index=True)
```

For example

```
SELECT ••• `FROM "shop_push_shoppushqueue" 
WHERE "shop_push_shoppushqueue"."record_updated" >= '2021-12-18T16:25:15.485671+00:00'::timestamptz 
GROUP BY "shop_push_shoppushqueue"."customer_name", DATE_TRUNC('day', "shop_push_`shoppushqueue"."record_updated" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London') 
ORDER BY "date" DESC
```

There is an index on customer_name

Is there anything else I could be doing to datetime fields to make them quicker?

ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS
[('GroupAggregate (cost=628122.43..650674.95 rows=902101 width=9) (actual time=2433.611..2739.113 rows=69 loops=1)',), (" Output: processed, (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('Europe/London'::text, record_updated))), count(processed)",), (" Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('Europe/London'::text, shop_push_shoppushqueue.record_updated))), shop_push_shoppushqueue.processed",), (' Buffers: shared hit=8 read=219403 written=6, temp read=2829 written=2829',), (' -> Sort (cost=628122.43..630377.68 rows=902101 width=9) (actual time=2433.597..2625.038 rows=894470 loops=1)',), (" Output: processed, (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('Europe/London'::text, record_updated)))",), (" Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('Europe/London'::text, shop_push_shoppushqueue.record_updated))) DESC, shop_push_shoppushqueue.processed",), (' Sort Method: external merge Disk: 22552kB',), (' Buffers: shared hit=8 read=219403 written=6, temp read=2829 written=2829',), (' -> Bitmap Heap Scan on public.shop_push_shoppushqueue (cost=17631.71..523473.93 rows=902101 width=9) (actual time=151.496..1915.533 rows=894470 loops=1)',), (" Output: processed, date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('Europe/London'::text, record_updated))",), (" Recheck Cond: (shop_push_shoppushqueue.record_updated >= '2021-12-21 15:06:33.5759+00'::timestamp with time zone)",), (' Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 84951',), (' Heap Blocks: exact=31137 lossy=185595',), (' Buffers: shared read=219403 written=6',), (' -> Bitmap Index Scan on shop_push_shoppushqueue_record_updated_97aac1aa (cost=0.00..17406.19 rows=902101 width=0) (actual time=144.662..144.662 rows=894470 loops=1)',), (" Index Cond: (shop_push_shoppushqueue.record_updated >= '2021-12-21 15:06:33.5759+00'::timestamp with time zone)",), (' Buffers: shared read=2671',), ('Planning time: 0.836 ms',), ('Execution time: 2743.410 ms',)]

table schema
[('id', 'integer', None, "nextval('shop_push_shoppushqueue_id_seq'::regclass)", 'NO'), ('created', 'timestamp with time zone', None, None, 'NO'), ('product_id', 'character varying', 32, None, 'NO'), ('change_type', 'character varying', 32, None, 'NO'), ('processed', 'boolean', None, None, 'YES'), ('retries_remaining', 'integer', None, None, 'NO'), ('hash', 'character varying', 64, None, 'NO'), ('log', 'text', None, None, 'NO'), ('last_status_code', 'character varying', 16, None, 'NO'), ('internal_product_id', 'character varying', 16, None, 'YES'), ('record_updated', 'timestamp with time zone', None, None, 'NO'), ('shop_action', 'character varying', 64, None, 'NO'), ('shopapi_id', 'integer', None, None, 'YES'), ('change_source', 'character varying', 256, None, 'NO'), ('product_title', 'character varying', 1000, None, 'NO'), ('skipped_list', 'character varying', 200, None, 'NO'), ('product_handle', 'character varying', 300, None, 'NO'), ('sent_payload', 'jsonb', None, None, 'YES'), ('last_response', 'jsonb', None, None, 'YES'), ('last_message', 'text', None, None, 'NO'), ('customer_name', 'character varying', 32, None, 'YES'), ('from_queue_name', 'character varying', 200, None, 'YES'), ('isbn', 'character varying', 32, None, 'NO'), ('destination_provider', 'character varying', 32, None, 'YES'), ('priority', 'integer', None, None, 'NO'), ('validate_data', 'jsonb', None, None, 'NO'), ('bucket_actual', 'integer', None, None, 'YES'), ('bucket_available', 'integer', None, None, 'YES'), ('bucket_predicted', 'integer', None, None, 'YES'), ('group_items_by', 'character varying', 300, None, 'YES'), ('debug_details', 'jsonb', None, None, 'YES'), ('collection_message', 'text', None, None, 'NO'), ('redirect_message', 'text', None, None, 'NO'), ('activity_log', 'jsonb', None, None, 'NO')]

Thanks

Grant

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) from this query and share the DDL for this table, including the index definitions?

Comment: Sure.  Just added more information (not greatly formatted).  I am using Django, if that makes a difference

Comment: Could you use https://explain.dalibo.com and share the query plan with us? You also get much better DDL directly from the database, by using psql or pg_dump. I have no idea what "None"  means in your dump, that is not something used by SQL.

Comment: By the way, it looks like your work_mem is pretty low. Could you change it to something like 100MB? SET work_mem TO '100MB'; and then do the EXPLAIN? And even better, change this configuration setting in your database, so all queries benefit from some memory.

Comment: I also don't understand what GROUP BY is doing in your query, you kept half the SQL out.